# Do we need to module for indirect dependencies when create Guice injector?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

When create an injector to create an object, do we need include modules for its indirect dependencies?

For example, in the following code, how should we create the injector in main()?

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    @Inject
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Injector injector = Guice.getInjector(new BarModule());
        // or Injector injector = Guice.getInjector(new BarModule(), new BarDepModule());
        Foo foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
    }
}

//=====================
public interface Bar {}

public class BarImp {
    private BarDep barDep; // Dependency of Bar

    @Inject
    public Bar(BarDep barDep) {
        this.barDep = barDep;
    }
}
//=====================
```

Of course, there should be a binding for BarDep. The question is should we explicitly load BarDepModule or should BarModule be responsible for that?

Answer (score 0):

Fred Faber gave a nice talk that covers some best practices for this (but I couldn't find the slides online). His suggestion is to structure module installation vertically: the highest level component is responsible for installing all dependencies. In this case main should bind both BarModule and BarDepModule. In the future if you have some NachoModule that also happens to depend on BarDepModule you won't encounter binding conflicts if you take this approach...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is exactly the strategy.  Having the highest level module install the dependencies makes it clear exactly how a server/app is configured.  This helps the reader understand how a server is configured, and should eliminate potential binding conflicts (as illustrated by the Nacho example).  The slides to the presentation are here:  http://bit.ly/BigGuice2011

Comment: Thanks, Fred. I understand the potential of module conflict. However, what if there is a lot of clients of Bar and if BarImp changes and add a new dependency, say interface BarDep2? Then all Bar's clients need to update their code to add BarDep2Module.

Comment: Besides, does this violate the encapsulation principle because the clients of Bar need know the implementation (dependencies) of Bar?